# Is it better to find most highly related posts by tag with CouchDB or RDBMS?

Tags: mapreduce, tags, couchdb, rdbms, intersection

I want to find related posts by finding posts with the highest number of tags in common with the post in question. I can do this in a SQL query, but since I'll have thousands of posts with dozens of tags each I was wondering if CouchDB would be a better option? If so, how would it work in CouchDB?

Thinking about this problem relationally, here is the structure:

```
post: id, (other post data)
tag: id, (other tag data)
post_tag: post_id, tag_id
```

SQL to find the top 10 most related posts for post #X:

```
select r.post_id
from post_tag p join post_tag r on p.tag_id = r.tag_id
where p.post_id = X and r.post_id != X
group by r.post_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

This query gives the top 10 posts with the most tags in common with post X.

Can I get the same results from CouchDB more efficiently? How?

Comment: Perhaps what solves your problem is not a SQL or map/reduce database query, but search server... In Apache projects ([Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)) there is "more like this" query, which finds (suggests) documents similar to the requested one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This query gives the top 10 posts with the most tags in common with post X.

This kind of queries is horrible to compute with Map/Reduce, since, for every document, you would have to generate a key for every combination of tags. Moreover, you would need several chained map/reduces to achieve that efficiently. So CouchDB is definitely not the easy way to do that.

As Marcin wrote, you could "cheat" and use a search server over CouchDB, but your SQL query seems to be more elegant.

Comment: ok, thanks. After reading some on couchdb, I had a feeling that this wasnt a good use case for it, but it was suggested to me so I wanted to double-check in case I just wasnt thinking about it in the right way.